# WindowsError:[Error 123] When Replace in filename "%3" by ":"

Tags: python-2.7, replace, filenames

I am running this script:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    newname = filename.replace("%3",":")
    if newname != filename:
        os.rename(filename,newname)
```

which throws:

> WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume
>   label syntax is incorrect:

Any idea why this happens?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you want to write `newname = filename.replace("%3", ":")`?

Comment: Windows file names aren't allowed to contain colons.

Comment: @user4759923  I just edit, thanks

Comment: @Kevin That is what is happening to me, maybe I should  find other way , maybe change “%3” by “-” for example, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows files cannot contain the ':' character:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247) (or any of `\ / : * ? " < > |` as they are reserved characters.)

Try:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    newname = filename.replace("%3","-")
    if newname != filename:
        os.rename(filename,newname)
```